# How is selected the type of list returned by Collectors.toList()?

Tags: java, collections

The documentation of [Collectors.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) says that there are no guarantees on the type returned.

On a simple test:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("Geeks", 
                                 "for", 
                                 "GeeksforGeeks", 
                                 "Geeks Classes"); 

List<String> myList = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The type of `myList` is ArrayList.

[image: T]

How this type is selected? What conditions may change the type returned ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a API provision about future changes.
In the facts, an `ArrayList` is returned :

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
}
```

But what the specification tells is that the `toList()` method is not designed/engaged to return a specific `List` implementation.
Today, the implementation shows that `ArrayList` is returned, but tomorrow, a new Java version could return another implementation (why not an immutable List).
So clients of that method should not consider (at least theoretically) that an `ArrayList` will always be returned.

As a side note, `Collectors.toCollection(Supplier)` allows client to supply the collection to use for the collect.
While rarely used, you could use it to guarantee that an `ArrayList` is used :

```
List<String> list = l.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Actually, [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList%28%29) specifically tells us that “There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned.”  The specification explicitly states that no specific implementation can be assumed.

Comment: @VGR  You are right. I reformulated.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Collectors#toCollection(Supplier)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-); you can predetermine which type you want.

e.g.

```
Stream.of("a","b","c").collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Will return a new ArrayList.

Or for LinkedList

```
Stream.of("a","b","c").collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Both of the examples use the zero argument constructors of the datatypes.

And [Collectors#toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) does not guarantee any specific type. Thus the type return in theory, can differ by java version.

Comment: What would the syntax look like, if you weren't to use "LinkedList::new", is it something along the lines of "LinkedList.new()" or something?

Comment: Java 8 added in lamdba expressions and method references. LinkedList::new is a method reference to a constructor of LinkedList. As your example, you would be trying to reference a static method, which is allowed but you can't name methods with keywords, which 'new' is one. Otherwise the syntax is the same '[Class]::[methodName]' for a method reference. Or if it's a local non-statis reference this::[methodName] will work.